# Menu com banners laterais

Tags: html, css

Venho trabalhando em um projeto que necessita da implantação de um pedido que aproveite os espaços brancos para que sejam colocados banners de divulgação. Lido com uma estrutura já determinada e diversas vezes tenho problemas de implantação de alguma coisa nova, tendo que apelar as vezes a algumas atitudes não semanticas.

O projeto segue um modelo assim parecido com esse (o original tem MUITAS classes e eu não tenho total acesso, por isso o modelo):

```
<div class="borda-background">
    <ul class="menu-container">
        <li class="departamento">
            <a href="#">Categoria</a>
            <ul class="categoria-container">
                <li class="categorias-opcoes"><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                <li class="categorias-opcoes"><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                <li class="categorias-opcoes"><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                <li class="categorias-opcoes"><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                <li class="categorias-opcoes"><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="departamento">
            <a href="#">Categoria</a>
            <ul class="categoria-container">
                <li class="categorias-opcoes"><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                <li class="categorias-opcoes"><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                <li class="categorias-opcoes"><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                <li class="categorias-opcoes"><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                <li class="categorias-opcoes"><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="departamento">
            <a href="#">Categoria</a>
            <ul class="categoria-container">
                <li class="categorias-opcoes"><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                <li class="categorias-opcoes"><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                <li class="categorias-opcoes"><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                <li class="categorias-opcoes"><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                <li class="categorias-opcoes"><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="departamento">
            <a href="#">Categoria</a>
            <ul class="categoria-container">
                <li class="categorias-opcoes"><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                <li class="categorias-opcoes"><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                <li class="categorias-opcoes"><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                <li class="categorias-opcoes"><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                <li class="categorias-opcoes"><a href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Porém, ao tentar introduzir um banner em uma li extra em cada categoria, por exemplo, não obtenho sucesso, pois os heights variam de um browser para o outro. A intenção seria a de conseguir esse modelo com um container de 1000px e com a imagem sempre se adaptando de acordo com o número de "rows" de cada departamento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Velho, pessoalmente fica complicado dar um help assim.. tem inúmeras formas de se criar CSS pra atender seu objetivo... não tem ao menos algo pronto pra dar como exemplo? Algum site com o mesmo procedimento que voce tenha visto e etc..

Comment: A gente tem um exemplo real postado no site, mas com esses bugs cross browser. Na realidade, acabo não postando as informações devido a estrutura original do código que está bem decadente, e por ser gerado por outros, não da minha parte.

Comment: Você pode usar javascript para pegar o height da ul menu-container e aplicar no height da sua imagem.

Comment: Onde está o CSS relevante para estas classes?

Answer (score 0):

Jhonny, não use javascript para igualar os heights. Você pode usar [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) para que os boxes tenham a mesma altura, usando a propriedade "align-items". Contudo esta técnica é compatível com Internet Explorer versão 10 ou superior. 
Sendo assim, caso você queira igualar as alturas em navegadores mais antigos, você pode definir os estilos da estrutura como tabela, como [neste exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/sj1jh8on/) (atente-se para "display: table" e table-layout: fixed;). Depois disso, defina que a imagem tenha altura de 100%.